# Trying to sort a SQL Server table with many columns into one with only two columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server table that I need help sorting. My current table has the first column containing information called Parent, the subsequent columns are children, up to 21 of them called child1, child2, child3, .....

Example

```
Parent    Child1     Child2     Child3   .......  
001          003        004  
002          005        006        009
```

I need to sort the table such that my result will have two columns. The fist column will contain the Parent the second column would be Children and it would contain each child associated with it's parent.

Example

```
Parent     Children  
001            003  
001            004  
002            005  
002            006  
002            009
```

and so on.

I am fairly new to SQL and I'm not sure how to approach this. Any thoughts?

Comment: Check CROSS APPLY or UNPIVOT features and try to figure yourself a solution.

Answer (score -1):

Standard queries cannot produce multiple rows out single rows, but you can hack together ugly stuff like:

```
SELECT Parent, Child1
FROM yourtable

UNION ALL

SELECT Parent, Child2
FROM yourtable

UNION ALL 

etc...
```

where you repeat the union/select for every "child" column you want combined.

Comment: Does an `UNPIVOT` not do exactly what OP wants?

Comment: wouldn't be surprised. I don't deal with tsql enough though

Comment: Fair enough, I only phrased it as a question because I wasn't certain myself.

Answer (score -1):

Try `UNPIVOT`:

```
select 
    parent, child,
    val
from (
    select 001 as parent, 003 as child1, 004  as child2, 007 as child3 union all 
    select 002, 005, 006, 009
) x
unpivot (
    val for child in (child1, child2, child3)
) y
```

The only problem is that you have to explicitly list every column, so if child columns number is varying, you'll have to go with dynamic sql.

Answer (score -1):

An `UNPIVOT` does this

```
SELECT Parent, Child FROM table
UNPIVOT (Child FOR ChildNo IN (Child1, Child2, Child3)) u
```

[Working ON SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/202b9/2/0)

Obviously in your actual query, you'd add `Child4` to `Child21` to that comma separated list.